# Quartz scheduler in cluster mode: do high-frequent and low-frequent trigger fire on random nodes?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz

I've read the following statement about the Quartz cluster mode [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-11.html):

> Only one node will fire the job for each firing. What I mean by that is, if the job has a repeating trigger that tells it to fire every 10 seconds, then at 12:00:00 exactly one node will run the job, and at 12:00:10 exactly one node will run the job, etc. **It won’t necessarily be the same node each time - it will more or less be random which node runs it. The load balancing mechanism is near-random for busy schedulers (lots of triggers) but favors the same node that just was just active for non-busy (e.g. one or two triggers) schedulers**.

If I have several triggers (say, 10), both high-frequent (e.g. every 10 seconds) and low frequent (e.g. only once a day 01:00 pm), will both trigger types cause the jobs getting executed on different (random) nodes? Or does "lots of triggers" only refer to the hight-frequent triggers?

I would assume that also the "low frequent triggers" (just once a day) will cause the jobs to be executed on random nodes as there are a lot of triggers "near their execution time" (the high frequent ones), so from the perspective of Quartz at around 01:00 pm there are a lot of triggers present.

Answer (score 0):

Each Quartz instance polls the database at a specific interval, controlled by a property **org.quartz.scheduler.idleWaitTime**

> Is the amount of time in milliseconds that the scheduler will wait before re-queries for available triggers when the scheduler is otherwise idle. Normally you should not have to 'tune' this parameter, unless you’re using XA transactions, and are having problems with delayed firings of triggers that should fire immediately. Values less than 5000 ms are not recommended as it will cause excessive database querying. Values less than 1000 are not legal.

The default value for this property is 30 seconds

And another property controls how many threads can be run in parallel, **org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount**

> Can be any positive integer, although you should realize that only numbers between 1 and 100 are very practical. This is the number of threads that are available for concurrent execution of jobs. If you only have a few jobs that fire a few times a day, then 1 thread is plenty! If you have tens of thousands of jobs, with many firing every minute, then you probably want a thread count more like 50 or 100 (this highly depends on the nature of the work that your jobs perform, and your systems resources!).

[Link to documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/configuration.html)

With these two properties configured, I think load balancing depends on which instance polled the database first to get lock on the trigger and which instance has its threads free to pick up a job.

For non-busy schedulers, especially with all instances having the same interval, jobs can favor the instance which polls the database first for every minute.